# Yii addCondition doesnt work

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to add a very simple condition and it doesnt return me any data.

this is my search() code.

```
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
    $criteria->compare('title', $this->title, true);
    $criteria->compare('content', $this->content, true);
    $criteria->compare('categoryId', $this->categoryId);
    $criteria->compare('tags', $this->tags, true);
    $criteria->compare('createdById', $this->createdById);
    $criteria->compare('createdAt', $this->createdAt, true);
    $criteria->compare('updatedById', $this->updatedById);
    $criteria->compare('updatedAt', $this->updatedAt, true);
    $criteria->compare('status', $this->status);


    if (!TK::isEmpty($this->tags)) {
        $criteria->addCondition('t.id IN ('.'1,2,3'.')');
    }

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
}
```

I cant understand why this part is not working, **$criteria->addCondition('t.id IN ('.'1,2,3'.')');**

I just want to get data for matching id.

Comment: dump the $criteria and see exactly what sql query is it executing to fetch records. Run that query in your phpMyAdmin if you are using wamp. Have you checked that "!TK::isEmpty($this->tags)" is returning true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use `addInCondition`, e.g. :

```
$criteria->addInCondition('id', array(1,2,3));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail

Comment: you are suggesting to use addInCondition but in your code you are using again addCondition. Did you mean it that way?